# primeNG filtering not filtering the data

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to filter the columns in primeNG table, but it doesn't work. When I input some text, all the data disappears from table.

```js
<p-table #table [value]="datas">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th [pSortableColumn]="name">
                <span>Name
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="name"></p-sortIcon>
                </span>
                <input class="column-filter-input" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" pInputText type="text" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, name, 'contains')" [value]="table.filters['name']?.value" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field name should be string so it should be `table.filter($event.target.value, 'name', 'contains')` instead of `table.filter($event.target.value, name, 'contains')` like

```
<input class="column-filter-input" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" pInputText type="text" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, 'name', 'contains')" [value]="table.filters['name']?.value" />
```